# Pack targets into nuget for clients

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I'm creating nuget package that have some targets that should be installed for developers that use my package, i.e. in file `my-targets.targets` I have this lines:

```
  <Target Name="CleanGenerated" AfterTargets="Clean">
    ... do smthing ...
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Generate" BeforeTargets="Build">
    ... do smthing ...
  </Target>
```

How should I embeded this file with nuget so other developers would have those 2 build steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#including-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package), section "Including MSBuild props and targets in a package" you can read that you need to create a file with a ".targets" extension. Place that file in a "build" directory below the project root. In the NuSpec file  you need to add a reference to that section:

```
<metadata>
  ...
</metadata>
<files>
   <file src="build\**" target="build" />
</files>
```

Depending on your NuGet version the installation of the package will behave differently; see the documentation for more details.